# SOQL Ids on a related list

Tags: soql, query, childrelationship

I want to query ids on a related list from a lead. When I look up the related list name in the wsdl it says:

```
<complexType name="Lead">
<element name="signrequest__SignRequests__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
```

But when I run the following query:

```
SELECT Id, signrequest__SignRequests__r.Id FROM Lead
```

I get this error:

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:12

Comment: For better solution you need to post your code and exact error what you have received.

Comment: @Nihar this is my code from the Query editor in the Dev. console

Comment: What i understood is : `Lead` is Parent and `signrequest__SignRequests__c` child of `Lead`, you are suppose to get the Id of child from Lead. right ?

Comment: @Nihar Indeed, Lead is Parent and signrequest__SignRequests__c child of Lead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the related list records by using the following query,

Do the following steps :

1. Go to your `signrequest__SignRequests__c` object
2. Click on your Parent object lookup field (here you are using `LEAD`)
3. copy the child relationship name from this lookup field (See image i have used parent Account & child contact to show you example)
4. Use this child relationship name to your inner query.
5. Finally you can use the following query to your developer console and you will get your expected result.

   ```
   Select Id, (select Id from `Your child relationship name`) from Lead
   ```

[image]

Comment: the the child relationship name from the lookup field didnt work but the wsdl name did so the solution was: Select Id, (select Id,Name from signrequest__SignRequests__r) from Lead      Thanks!!

Comment: Nice work !!! :)

Comment: @ Nihar how do I do a second inner query, i want to get the attachment fields, the following didnt work: `SELECT Id,(SELECT Id,Name (SELECT Name, Body FROM NotesAndAttachments) FROM signrequest__SignRequests__r) FROM Lead`  I get the error: Unknown error parsing query

Comment: You can use this for getting Lead's attachments : `select Id , (select Id from Contacts), (Select Id from Attachments) from Account`

Comment: I meant attachments from signrequest__SignRequests__c, but I figured out you cant do 3rd level query from SOQL

Comment: Yes, exactly You can not do the same as expected.